# Counting five specific words in a file

Tags: java, strings, regex, file

I'm trying to improve my code and i want to know if this is the best way to write this Switch or if  there are other methods.

```
for(String word : words) {
        switch(word.toLowerCase()) {
        case "a":
            a++;
            break;
        case "the":
            the++;
            break;
        case "bird":
            bird++;
            break;
        case "animal":
            animal++;
            break;
        case "is":
            is++;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here is the complete code if you need it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
int a = 0, the = 0, bird = 0, animal = 0, is = 0;

    for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\n\\Desktop\\Text.txt"))) {
        line.split("\\s+");
        line.replaceAll("[!?.,]", "");
        for(String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
            words.add(word);
        }
    }

    for(String word : words) {
        switch(word.toLowerCase()) {
        case "a":
            a++;
            break;
        case "the":
            the++;
            break;
        case "bird":
            bird++;
            break;
        case "animal":
            animal++;
            break;
        case "is":
            is++;
            break;
        }
    }
System.out.println(a + " " + the + " " + bird + " " + animal + " " + is);
}
```

Comment: Is it your goal to **count** how many of a particular word you have found in the text file?

Comment: A better approach would be to have a `HashMap<String,Integer>`.

Comment: Yes, that's my goal.

Comment: `line.replaceAll("[!?.,]", "");` will not affect original string, but will create new one with replaced (or in this case removed) characters so if you want to update `line` you should store this new string like `line = line.replaceAll("[!?.,]", "");`.

Comment: Weird. I printed out all the words and none had symbols.

Comment: This means that there ware none such symbols in a line, or you removed them somewhere else. `line.replaceAll("[!?.,]", "");` does nothing here (strings are immutable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a better, more efficient and compact way:

```
    String path = "C:/Users/n/Desktop/Text.txt";

    List<String> targetList = Arrays.asList("a", "the", "bird", "animal", "is");
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>(targetList.size());
    for (String word : targetList) {
        counts.put(word, 0);
    }

    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path))) {
        for (String word : line.replaceAll("[!?.,]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+")) {
            Integer count = counts.get(word);
            if (count != null) {
                counts.put(word, count + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print(counts.get(targetList.get(0)));
    for (int i = 1; i < targetList.size(); ++i) {
        String word = targetList.get(i);
        System.out.print(" " + counts.get(word));
    }
    System.out.println();
```

The improvements and corrections:

- It's good to define constants like the path high up in a file where they are easy to change and easy to change, without having to read into the details of the code
- It's simpler to write paths with forward slashes
- Use interface type like `List` when defining a list instead of implementation type like `ArrayList`
- Since it seems you're only interested in a specific set of words:

  - I put them in a list for ordering
  - ... then initialized the map of counts to all 0 values
- Instead of building a list of words, it's more efficient to do the counting at the same time as you read the words. This will save you both storage and processing time
- When you do `line.replaceAll("[!?.,]", "")`, the operation is not performed on `line`, as strings in Java are immutable. The result with the characters removed is returned
- The same goes for a `line.split("\\s+")` statement you had. If you don't save the result of the operation, then it's completely pointless

Answer (score 10):

You can use a Map :

```
Map<String,Integer> freq = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(String word : words) {
    String w = word.toLowerCase();
    if (freq.containsKey(w)) {
        freq.put(w,freq.get(w)+1);
    } else {
        freq.put(w,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused how this works. I have read the java docs and I'm still confused.

Comment: @Vincent Map stores key-value pairs. Key needs to be unique, values not. We can use map which will be storing `word<String>-count<Integer>` pair. If you are putting word into map first time (if map doesn't have it) you can place pair `word,1`, but if map already have such word you need to put into map this word with new value, which will be equal to old value + 1 (you want to increase counter by `get`ting old counter and adding 1 to it).

Comment: @Vincent Instead of having a different variable that counts the occurences of each word, you use a Map, where the key is the word and the value is the number of occurences. If the current word is not in the Map, you add it to the Map with a initial count of 1. If it's already in the Map, you increment the count by 1. In the end, freq.get("bird") would return the value that the `bird` variable holds in your implementation.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was excellent and I understand now.

Comment: would you please insert the explanation into the answer? Thank you.

Comment: Rather than having the map store `Integer` objects, I'd suggest that perhaps storing instances of `int[1]`, or a class which exposes a single public field of type `int` but has no other functionality, might be better. Using such a design, updating a count only requires one hash-table lookup; otherwise each update will require a lookup to read the old value and another for the new value.

Comment: Also, if you're using guava you can use a [`MultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)